# How to get value of element using text in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I've got a problem using BeautifulSoup. I need to get the value of the element using only some text inside but I've got no idea how to do that. There's some HTML code:

```html
<option class="" value="9_72"> 42,5 EUR · 9 US </option>
<option class="" value="9_73"> 43 EUR · 9,5 US </option>
<option class="" value="9_74"> 44 EUR · 10 US </option>
```

Is there any posibility to get it?

I tried this code:

```py
scraper = cfscrape.create_scraper()
content_rdy = scraper.get(link, headers=headers).text
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(content_rdy, 'lxml')

input_id = soup.find_all('option', text='44 EUR')
print(input_id)
```

but it gives me empty `[]`.  If I use:

```py
input_id = soup.find_all('option')
```

I can't get exact the value of the option. And the problem is that the only thing how I can get this value is the size inside this element.

I want to get this -> value="**9_72**"

Comment: What result do you want to get? This one: `<option class="" value="9_74"> 44 EUR · 10 US </option>`?

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = """
<option class="" value="9_72"> 42,5 EUR · 9 US </option>
<option class="" value="9_73"> 43 EUR · 9,5 US </option>
<option class="" value="9_74"> 44 EUR · 10 US </option>"""

soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')

options = [option for option in soup.find_all('option') if '44 EUR' in option.text]
values = [option.get("value") for option in options]
```

it returns all tags, who text contains "44 EUR" string

Comment: Thank you it works, is it possible to get value now? i mean 9_72 for example

Comment: Yes it possible. ```option.get("value")``` returns value of atribute ```value```, where ```option``` is element from ```options``` list

Comment: I tried this but it wont work i've got error like this "ResultSet object has no attribute 'get'"

Comment: it's should be object of ```BeautifulSoup```

Comment: If it is 'str' object or other, then there are not method ```get```, copy my answer and try again. It works.

Comment: I've edited it a bit but finall it works perfectly :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add this after the line:

```
input_id = soup.find_all('option')
for options in input_id:
    option_text = options.text 
    if '44 EUR' in options_text:
       final_options_text = options_text

print(final_options_text)
```

Essentially you can iterate over the result set and do a wild card match to see which of the tags has the text you need.